# How to change IdeaVim motion key in a specific mode

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

I am a vim addict with a personnalized keyboard layout derivated of bépo and I want to remap IdeaVim motion keys **«hjkl»** in visual mode to **«ctsr»**.

I tried to change this from the setting panel but it changed the motion key for both visual and insert mode and when I want to insert a character from one of my motion key it instead moves.

I tried to adapt the vim.xml without success.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: You should submit a feature request at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM. You may also get the plug-in source code from GitHub and try to implement it yourself, then send a patch/pull request to the developers.

Comment: I wanted to know if it is possible to do via setting and if it is how to do. But it doesn't seem to be so I opened a request like you advice. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-295

Comment: Probably possible now in version 0.33, with the implementation of VIM-288?  Most of my bindings are for normal mode and they work well, but I think I tried a few for visual mode too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no longer impossible. IdeaVim version 0.35 (released 2014-05-15) and later read vim settings and key bindings from `~/.ideavimrc`.  You can put `source ~/.vimrc` in that file if you want to include mappings from `~/.vimrc`.

0.33 (released 2014-04-28) was the first version to implement [VIM-288](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/VIM-288), including things like mapping <kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> to <kbd>ESC</kbd>.  It works very well, and there's a new *Vim Emulation* section in the IDEA preferences that lists all the conflicts between `~/.vimrc` mappings and Intellij mappings, and lets you resolve the conflicts by assigning the keys to either IDEA or IdeaVim.  Here is the [release announcement](https://twitter.com/ideavim/status/460815026413404160) on twitter.

Comment: I am not a vim user anymore (emacs lover now), but thank you :)

Comment: They're not mutually exclusive, you know.  I'm a big fan of emacs evil-mode.  =)